# Find the sum of an infinite series that involve a discrete random variable

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, self-learning

I need to find the sum of the following series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{X_n}{e^{n}}$ ,  where $X_n$ be I.I.D ,$P(X_n=1)=\frac12$ or $P(X_n=-1)=\frac12$

Using the ratio test, it can be shown that this series is convergent.Because,

$\lim  \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|= lim \left| \frac{{1}}{e} \right|$<1 .

But is there any method to find the actual sum ??

can i split this sum as $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{n}}$ - $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{n}}$ since $X_n$ can only take 1 and -1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You are only given the distribution of $X_n$'s and not a specific definition as functions on a sample space. You cannot write down the sum of the series. But one cans show that the series converges with probability $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My goal is to show that this  sum  equals to zero. Hence this series has a Lebesgue measure of zero , if that is possible. Can you suggest any approach to do that ?

Comment: @Statlover The sum is not $0$ and you cannot evaluate the sum.

Comment: @Statlover The variance of the infinite sum will be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-2n} = \frac{e^{-2}}{1-e^{-2}}>0$. The sum cannot be equal to $0$ a.s...

Comment: @Statlover The key here is that the different 'realizations' of the randomness (i.e. the different $\omega$ in the sample space $\Omega$) will yield different values for the $X_i$. You have seen that with probability one their sum will converge. However it will converge to different values for different realizations of the $X_i.$ The sum is a random variable, just like the $X_i.$ We can define it formally as $S(\omega) = \limsup_n \sum_{i=1}^nX_i(\omega)$ (we use limsup so it will always exist, even for the (possible) null set of $\omega$'s for which the sum diverges.)

Comment: Since my intention is to show the sum of this series goes to zero, will it be possible to relate this to a distribution of a cantor set ? In that way i may be able to tell that this distribution has a Lebesgue measure  of zero.

Comment: Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-k}X_k$ and $S=\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$.. Note that $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty e^{-k} = \frac1{e(e-1)} \approx 0.214, $$ so $$\mathbb P(S >1/2) \geqslant \mathbb P(X_1=1) = \frac12$$
and similarly $\mathbb P(S<-1/2)=1/2$. So $S_n$ does not converge almost surely to zero.

Comment: Well ,believe that this is a question that asked in an assignment . The actual question is to "show that the above distribution of the above series  is singular or it is concentrated on a set  of Lebesgue measure zero. To answer that question i thought to find the sum of this series.  Seems like there is a problem with this question

Comment: @Statlover That is not remotely the same thing as saying the sum of the series goes to zero. This is a good example of why you should always include the actual question and not just what you think the question is. (I think they call this an XY problem)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen My bad. According to my knowledge i thought it is the same. I am sorry. Anyway can you suggest any starting point ? The only thing i learnt of Lebesgue measure of zero is construction of vitali set and cantor set. So there may be a easier way to show this.

Comment: @Statlover Well a Vitali set is not measurable, but yes this concentrates on a Cantor-like set of measure zero. The seeds of this are actually in Math1000's hint above where we see that the $S$ is excluded from the interval $(-.154, .154).$ (They actually make a small error here when they say $P(S>1/2)$... it should be $P(S>1/e-.214)$)

Comment: @Statlover (Recall how the Cantor set can be constructed by recursively removing intervals. Here we can show a similar set of intervals, whose measure totals all that of $[-1/(1-e),1/(1-e)],$ is not in the support of $S$ by iterating Math1000's reasoning.)

Comment: I appreciate your help . Thank you. I will work on this

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I was considering the series starting at index $0$ when I wrote that, but the same logic applies.